# Nonzerodivisor can be chosen linear?

Tags: polynomials, modules, ideals, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $R = k[x_1, \ldots, x_n$] be a graded ring with $deg(x_i) = 1 \ \forall i = 1, \ldots, n$ and let $\mathfrak{m} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be the graded maximal ideal. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module.
Assume that $\mathfrak{m}$ contains a nonzerodivisor $x$ on M, i.e. $x$ is $M$-regular.

Can we always chose $x$ to be linear, i.e. $x \in \mathfrak{m}_1$?

What I was thinking, is that if by contradiction all linear elements are zerodivsors on $M$, then $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are zerodivisors on $M$.  Wouldn't that mean that all monomials are zerodiviors and therefore all elements in $\mathfrak{m}$ are zerodivisors on $M$?

I know of a proof in Bruns and Herzog's *Cohen-Macaulay rings* (Prop. 1.5.12), but there they need the assumption that $k$ is infinite. So I was wondering, where my proof fails, i.e. why this would not hold for a finite field $k$?

Comment: What is the role of $M$ in your question?

Comment: I forgot to mention that $x$ should be a nonzerodivisor on $M$, i.e. an $M$-regular element. I've edited the question.

Comment: Maybe a silly question (it's late...) but why would a sum of zerodivisors need to be a zerodivisor?

Comment: I think you're right. The sum of zerodivisors doesn't need to be a zerodivisor. 
Do you happen to know any counterexample in the setting go my question, i.e. where the nonzerodivisor cannot be chosen linear?